# Domain of piecewise-defined functions composition

Tags: calculus, functions, function-and-relation-composition

I'm wondering what is the right way to perform function composition on those two functions:

$$f\left(x\right) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       1/x & : x \ne 0\\
       0 & : x = 0
     \end{array}
   \right.\\$$

$$g\left(t\right)=1/t$$

I want to create $f∘g$ and see what is the end result of the composition.
I know that it should be easy but I'm a little bit confused determining the domain and range of the new function.

Help would be appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: $fog(x)=f(g(x))$ which says that when you choose x, it should be in domain of $g$ and then values of $g(x)$ must be in the domain of $ f $ (if they are not then take the intersection of domain of $f$ and range of $g$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to calculate $f(g(t)) = f(1/t)$. We have
$$
f(1/t) = \cases{\frac1{1/t} = t& if $1/t \neq 0$\\0 & if $1/t = 0$}
$$
which is to say $f(g(t)) = t$. Note that since $g$ is undefined for $t = 0$, so is $f \circ g$. The function $f$ is defined for any real number, so there is no specific value of $t$ that makes $g(t)$ inadmissable as argument to $f$. The domain is therefore $\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$

Comment: Thank you, what about the case in which $(1/t)=0$ when looking at $f(1/t)$ This condition will never be fulfilled.

Comment: You mean the case when $1/t = 0$? That's right, that condition is never fulfilled, so we just drop it, and we get directly that $f(1/t) = t$.

Comment: Thank you very much, that what I was looking for!